# googlemaps reload markers based on input

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am trying to update markers on my google Map, which loads markers when the page is loaded, based on an input from a user. For example, the map loads markers from an xml based on a date, I have an input form on my webpage that when clicked users can change the date, and the markers would then reload based on the date selected. Here is my code so far: **JavaScript** -

```
  var finddate = document.getElementById('inputdate').value;

  jQuery.ajax({
    dataType :'xml', 
    type: 'GET',
    url : 'phps/xmltest.php?finddate='+finddate, 
    success:function(data){
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var dt1 = markers[i].getAttribute("date1");
      var dt2 = markers[i].getAttribute("date2");
      var dt3 = markers[i].getAttribute("date3");
      var tm1 = markers[i].getAttribute("time1");
      var tm2 = markers[i].getAttribute("time2");
      var tm3 = markers[i].getAttribute("time3");
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + "Date of Yard Sale: " + dt1 + '&nbsp;' + tm1 + '&nbsp;' + dt2 + '&nbsp;' + tm2 + '&nbsp;' + dt3 + '&nbsp;' + tm3 + '&nbsp;' + "<br/>" + address;
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: CustomMarker
      });

      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  }});
```

and the **PHP** -

```
   <?php


   // Check if we have parameters  being passed to the script through the URL
   if (isset($_GET["finddate"])) {


     $got = $_GET["finddate"];

     }

   if($got == "Today" || $got == "") { $date = date('m-d-Y');} else { $date = $got; }

   $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
   $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
  $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

   // Opens a connection to a MySQL server

 mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "PW");

 // Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("Registration2");
 if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
 }

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM REGISTERED2 WHERE DateONE = '$date' or DateTWO = '$date' or DateTHREE = '$date'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['Name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['Address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['Latitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['Longitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("date1", $row['DateONE']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("date2", $row['DateTWO']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("date3", $row['DateTHREE']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("time1", $row['TimeONE']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("time2", $row['TimeTWO']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("time3", $row['TimeTHREE']);

}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problems are you having?  What is working? What isn't working?  What does the xml look like?  Can you provide a fiddle that exhibits the problem you are having?

Comment: It's not updating. If I try a direct url like phps/xmltest.php?finddate=05-24-2014 that works, but if I assign it as the url in JS does not. Or it could be some other problem I'm not noticing here, but basically the it doesn't up date if I change the date.

Comment: How can we reproduce that?  How does the code you posted remove the existing markers (assuming that you expect it to)?

Comment: when the user enters the date into the form, I have an "onchange" event that calls the loadGoogleMaps(); and what it's supposed to do, assign the value from the input form to the "finddate" var in js.

Comment: I don't see a loadGoogleMaps function in your posted code.

Comment: I didn't include it because it simply runs the googleMaps api, to generate a map and load markers. I had it working all, the markers were loading based on a pre-set date, and everything worked find; now that I want the date to be variable that's where I'm running into a problem. If I include the rest of the code, it'll be too long for the comment section.